# xsl "following" returns not what was expected

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have xml like this:

```
  <ROWSET>
    <ROW>
      <FLD1>P2</FLD1>
      <S_VAL>1</S_VAL>    
      <FLD2>N2</FLD2>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
      <FLD1>P3</FLD1>
      <S_VAL>2</S_VAL> 
      <FLD2>N2</FLD2>    
    </ROW>
     <ROW>
      <FLD1>P3</FLD1>
      <S_VAL>3</S_VAL> 
      <FLD2>N2</FLD2>    
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
      <FLD1>P4</FLD1>
      <S_VAL>4</S_VAL>    
       <FLD2>N3</FLD2>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
      <FLD1>P2</FLD1>
      <S_VAL>5</S_VAL>    
      <FLD2>N3</FLD2>
    </ROW>
  </ROWSET>
```

And i have 2 variables in my xsl:

```
  <xsl:variable name="only_need" select="/ROWSET/ROW[./FLD2='N2']"/>
  <xsl:variable name="only_need2" select="$only_need/FLD1[not(.=following::FLD1)]"/>
```

In variable with name "only_need" I receive records with S_Val IN (1, 2, 3).
But in variable with name "only_need2" I receve only FLD1 = P3.
Question of why the second variable receve only FLD1 = P3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers you question from a comment to the good answer by Ian Roberts:

> Can you tell me, how can i use of "following" only for "only_need"

In fact, this is a pure XPath question.

**It is possible to avoid using keys and just use an axis such as "preceding" or "following" in finding "distinct" elements, however do keep in mind that this is very slow -- O(N^2) as comared to using keys -- (O(N)):**

```
 <xsl:variable name="vOnlyNeed" select="/*/*[FLD2='N2']"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vOnlyNeedDistinct" select=
  "$vOnlyNeed
   [not(FLD1
       =
        following::*
           [count(.|$vOnlyNeed) = count($vOnlyNeed)]
             /FLD1)]
   "/>
```

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vOnlyNeed" select="/*/*[FLD2='N2']"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vOnlyNeedDistinct" select=
  "$vOnlyNeed
   [not(FLD1
       =
        following::*
           [count(.|$vOnlyNeed) = count($vOnlyNeed)]
             /FLD1)]
   "/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="$vOnlyNeedDistinct"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<ROWSET>
    <ROW>
        <FLD1>P2</FLD1>
        <S_VAL>1</S_VAL>
        <FLD2>N2</FLD2>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <FLD1>P3</FLD1>
        <S_VAL>2</S_VAL>
        <FLD2>N2</FLD2>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <FLD1>P3</FLD1>
        <S_VAL>3</S_VAL>
        <FLD2>N2</FLD2>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <FLD1>P4</FLD1>
        <S_VAL>4</S_VAL>
        <FLD2>N3</FLD2>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <FLD1>P2</FLD1>
        <S_VAL>5</S_VAL>
        <FLD2>N3</FLD2>
    </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

**the Xpath expressions are evaluated and the contents of the so defined variable `$vOnlyNeedDistinct` is copied to the output**:

```
<ROW>
   <FLD1>P2</FLD1>
   <S_VAL>1</S_VAL>
   <FLD2>N2</FLD2>
</ROW>
<ROW>
   <FLD1>P3</FLD1>
   <S_VAL>3</S_VAL>
   <FLD2>N2</FLD2>
</ROW>
```

Comment: Only 10-15 records will be in $vOnlyNeed. All works like you sed. But not entirely clear how the filter works ` [count(.|$vOnlyNeed) = count($vOnlyNeed)] `

Comment: The trick is that XPath works on node _sets_, so  when you construct a union using `exprA | exprB` nodes that are matched by both expressions are only counted once.  Therefore `[count(.|$vOnlyNeed) = count($vOnlyNeed)]` is true if and only if the node in question (`.`) is a member of the set `$vOnlyNeed`.

Answer (score 1):

`only_need2` contains the `FLD1` children of those rows in `only_need` whose values are different from those of all following `FLD1` elements *in the whole document*, not just in `only_need`. So you don't get the `P2` because there's another `P2` later on (in the fifth row).

If what you want is actually the last row *from `only_need`* for each distinct `FLD1` value, you can do that using a key

```
<xsl:key name="key_only_need2" match="/ROWSET/ROW[FLD2='N2']/FLD1" use="." />
<xsl:variable name="only_need2" select="$only_need/FLD1[
      generate-id() = generate-id( key('key_only_need2', .)[last()] )]" />
```

What I'm doing here is defining a key that will extract all the `FLD1` elements from rows whose `FLD2` is `N2` and group them by their `FLD1` value.  The predicate in the variable declaration uses this key to select only the *last* element from each of these groups.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me, how can i use of "following" only for "only_need"